# Pandas cut, how to label the right open endpoint?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get the right open endpoint to map to a label with pd.cut?  For example the following snippet,
just shows the an interval not the label (e.g. '[10000000.0, 50000000.0)' instead of '$10 billion to $50 billion')?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

breaks = [0, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 50000000]  # actual values are in millions
labels = [
    'under $1 billion', 
    '$1 billion - $5 billion', 
    '$5 billion - $10 billion', 
    '$10 billion to $50 billion', 
    'over $50 billion'
]
interval = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(breaks, closed='left')

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(10000, 50000000, 20)})
df['Asset Size'] = pd.cut(df['value'], interval, labels=labels, right=False )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually use your breaks as bins in the `pd.cut`. Theres no need to use `pd.IntervalIndex`.

```
breaks = [0, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 50000000, np.inf]  # actual values are in millions
labels = [
    'under $1 billion', 
    '\$1 billion - $5 billion', 
    '\$5 billion - $10 billion', 
    '\$10 billion - $50 billion', 
    'over $50 billion']

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(0, 50000000, 20)})
df['Asset Size'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins = breaks, labels=labels, right=False)
```

The `\` is an escape for starting the string with a `$` symbol, and you also need to add `np.inf` to represent anything over 50 billion.